# JQuery selector not working properly on my multilevel navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple horizontal navigation bar with multiple levels (but for now, I've only made a navigation bar with one sublevel). I'm following this tutorial [here](http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/create-the-fanciest-dropdown-menu-you-ever-saw) with some modifications:

```
<ul id = "sample2">
    <li>
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Website</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Creator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Our Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Just give us money</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">FAQs</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">What is this?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Why should I care???</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Telephone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mobile Phone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">E-mail</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

I used only one id on the main `<ul>` and I'm accessing the sublevels using `#sample2 ul` instead of using classes on those.

However, it simply doesn't work when I use the JQuery codes:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sample2 ul').each(function () {
        $(this).parent().eq(0).hover(function () {
            $('#sample2 ul:eq(0)', this).show(100);
            }, function () {
            $('#sample2 ul:eq(0)', this).hide(100);
        });
    });
});
```

Again, I only changed the tutorial's `.dropdown` class to `#sample2 ul`.

But it does work if I do the same way as the tutorial (i.e. assign either an id or a class on the sublevels), although I think it's unnecessary since those sub-`<ul>`-s can be selected using css selectors.

What am I doing wrong? Are those sublevels really can only be selected using assigned classes/id on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXX7F/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#sample2').on('hover', 'li', showSubMenu);
    $('#sample2').on('mouseleave', hideSubMenus);
});

function showSubMenu(){
    $(this).siblings().children('ul').hide(100);
    $(this).children('ul').show(100);
}
function hideSubMenus(){
    $(this).find('ul').hide(100);
}
```

EDIT:
It seems like you have some confusion about jQuery and how to use selectors (particularly selectors with context e.g. `$(selector, context)`).

In your example, `$('#sample2 ul')` will select every `ul` that is a descendant of #sample 2.  If you wanted to add the same hover effect to each `ul`, `$('#sample2 ul').hover(handler)` or `$('#sample2 ul').on('hover', handler)` will do that for you.  The problem is, you can't hover over hidden items.  So what you really want is to select the `li` under #sample2 and attach your handler to their hover event.

Within your hover event handler, you use the selector `$('#sample2 ul:eq(0)', this)`.  The 'this' in that selector provides the context within which the `#sample2 ul:eq(0)`  will be looked for.  In an event handler, `this` refers to the element tied to that event.  In this case, the hovered-over `li`.   Eq(0) has no place inside the quotes of the selector, and as a general rule, should be avoided as part of any jQuery selector.  Because there is no `#sample2` element within the context of `this` and because the `:eq(0)` malforms the selector, `$('#sample2 ul:eq(0)', this)` will return an empty jQuery object (nothing selected).  What you wanted in your handler was `$(this).children('ul')`.  Which will get the `ul` that is a direct child of the li currently hovered over.

Answer (score 1):

`#sample2 ul` means get the `<UL>` element that is a child of the element with ID sample2.

What you are looking for is `ul#sample2` as a selector, which means get the `<UL>` element that has the ID sample2

Comment: True, but what I'm looking for is to  get the `<ul>` element that is a child of a `<ul>` element with an ID of `sample2`

Comment: `ul#sample2 ul` means `ul` that is the child of a `ul` with the id `#sample2`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need jquery for this. A bit of simple CSS will get the desired results:

```
​ul#sample2 li ul
{
    display:none;
}
​ul#sample2 li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
}​​​
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/hDGmV/)

Edit: Here's a 3-level example:

[**-- 3 LEVEL DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/hDGmV/1/)

Comment: i would like some sliding/fade effect eyecandy on it. that's why i choose to use JQuery..

Comment: @Curt IE6 only supports the `:hover` pseudo-selector on anchors.

Comment: All the views to IE6 came from a really small amout of people in China and the other half of views are from scared programmers.

Comment: @Alnitak Fair enough, I wasn't aware of that, and I don't care :) "Angry birds" doesn't work on Nokia 3210, but I'm not going to complain to the developers.

Comment: @GeraldTorres In that case you are better off using jQuery, I just went on what you had provided in your question.

Comment: @Curt But would I be better off using unnecessary classes / IDs (i think they're unnecessary) on all sublevels?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: got it this time, and I've tested it so I know this works, the following is the js you need:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sample2 ul').each(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('a').eq(0).hover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children('ul').show(100);
            }, function () {
            $(this).parent().children('ul').hide(100);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Calling the `<ul>` tag directly below `#sample2`? But isn't that `#sample2>ul`

Comment: I've always found that unless that 'li' is in between jquery wont recognise the tags within that `<li>` tag, try it and see.

Comment: ..it doesn't work. From what I know, to call a tag directly under another tag (like a `<p>` under a `<div>`), `div>p` could be used.

Comment: ..How come the submenus hide when I try to hover to it? I think those change back to being hidden whenever I take the mouse pointer out of the main `<ul>`. Still, thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sample2 > li').hover(
function() {
   // show
   $('ul', this).show(100);
},
function() {
  // hide
  $('ul', this).hide(100);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hxDmp/3/)

Comment: but all `<ul>` tags will be affected by this, yes?

Comment: I tried this. All the submenus appear when I hover to any part of the navigation bar with any sublevels.